# Next.js how to use SWC compiler with Material UI and swc-plugin-transform-import

Tags: javascript, next.js, material-ui, swc-compiler

I've been struggling with transforming imports with Next.js using SWC complier.

I'm trying to make use of [swc-plugin-transform-import](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swc-plugin-transform-import) as a replacement of [babel-plugin-transform-imports](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-imports) for shorting on Material UI imports.

As documented, I've tried with this settings. It shows experimental warning, but other than that it ignores plugin all together.

```js
// next.config.js

module.exports = {
  experimental: {
    swcPlugins: [
      [
        'swc-plugin-transform-import',
        {
          "@mui/material": {
            transform: "@mui/material/${member}",
            preventFullImport: true
          },
          "@mui/icons-material": {
            transform: "@mui/icons-material/${member}",
            preventFullImport: true
          },
          "@mui/styles": {
            transform: "@mui/styles/${member}",
            preventFullImport: true
          },
          "@mui/lab": {
            transform: "@mui/lab/${member}",
            preventFullImport: true
          }
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

Anyone knows how to enable and configure `swc-plugin-transform-import` for Next.js? Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oh I've found an answer in [Next.js Compiler Docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/compiler#modularize-imports).

```js
module.exports = {
  modularizeImports: {
    "@mui/material": {
      transform: "@mui/material/{{member}}"
    },
    "@mui/icons-material": {
      transform: "@mui/icons-material/{{member}}"
    },
    "@mui/styles": {
      transform: "@mui/styles/{{member}}"
    },
    "@mui/lab": {
      transform: "@mui/lab/{{member}}"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For anybody using Next.js version from `13.4.x` onwards, some popular packages now have `modularizeImports` preconfigured by Next.js (for example, `antd`, `mui`, `lodash` etc).

PR [1](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/50900) and [2](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/52031).